# How to check whether the iterator hit the end without container?

Tags: c++, stl

For example, how to implement the following function without any other information?

```
bool isEnd(set<int> :: iterator itr);
```

I know I can do it like this, but how to do it without input variable "s"?

```
bool isEnd(const set<int> &s, set<int> :: iterator itr) {
    return itr == s.end();
}
```

Comment: You can't. There's nothing in the iterator itself that indicates it's at the end, you need another iterator to compare it to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the standard C++ library, there is no way to write that.

`std::set` can be implemented as e.g. [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_black_tree), and then iterators are nodes inside, and you need the entire tree to figure out if that node is the last.

Comment: actually, with a rbtree like `std::set` the iterators are node pointers and `end()` is always a pointer to a special 'not an actual data node' node, so this would be easy.  The problematic case is `std::vector` where iterators are just pointers into the data array of the vector and you need the `size` of the vector to figure out when you've hit the end.

Answer (score 10):

You do not.

A range is two iterators, and you should almost always be working on a range when you are moving iterators around.

Containers are also ranges, so you can carry the container around instead, but usually you do not need the full container.

Comment: I'll have to disagree. For example in a String, you can easily check if the iterator points to end using `string::npos`, without ever having reference to the original string.

Comment: @ChiragArora You can tell if an **index** points "past" the end, but not an iterator.