# Is it possible to check if a string iterator is equal to its end iterator without the original string?

Tags: c++, string, iterator

Say I have some `std::string::iterator it` for some unknown string `str`. Is it possible for me to check when `it == str.end()` without access to `str` or `str.end()`?

Comment: That will be quite a trick indeed!  How did you get access to `it`?

Comment: Short answer: No.  `std::string` can have null characters in it, so you can't even just look forward for a null terminator.

Comment: I'm going to say the answer is "no", but that's not very interesting. Perhaps some more detail in the question will permit a solution.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555171, but there may well be something special about `std::string` iterators that allow this.

Answer (score 2):

An iterator is, logically, a *pointer*. It is not an index and a reference to a container. Therefore, you cannot get information about the container that contains the iterator item.

This is in some sense analogous to the pass-array-as-pointer problem: when you pass an array as a pointer, you also always have to pass the length, because the pointer does not identify where the array ends. Your iterator does not identify where the string ends.

As others have pointed out, a crude approach that *would work* in most situations is to check if the character pointed to by the iterator is the null character. This is ok, as long as your string doesn't contain any null characters; but remember that if you're dealing with strings as an interface boundary others may pass strings with null in them, because it is perfectly legal to do so.